# how to add keywords in Android manifest

Tags: android, manifest, keyword

i would like to know how to put keywords in Android manifest for more ranking in Google play store.
For example i want to use these keywords:

```
wifi-hotspot, wifi decrypter, wifi password, wifi hack, wifi code
```

Like this.
I will be glad if you could help me more. 
Thank you for your collaboration

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could.  THey found out early in the days of the web that self assigning keywords like that are a horrible model for accurate searches.

Comment: i think they remove it and only rely on play store smart name tagging

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of putting keywords in the Android manifest for use by any app distribution channel.